# Bookdown pdf output: less equal symbol in a table

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm writing a book using the bookdown package. I have a table that contains the less equal symbol with the `$\leq$`. When I render the book in HTML the symbol is visualized but I have to add one slash more `$\\leq$`. When i render the book in pdf the symbol is not rendered. How can I solve this?

My r code for the table:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}

table_vo2max_donne <- data.frame(Età = c("20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59","60-69", "70-79"),
                       Basso = c("$\\leq$ 35","$\\leq$ 33", "$\\leq$ 31", "$\\leq$ 28", "$\\leq$ 25", "$\\leq$ 23" ),
                       Normale = c("36-39", "34-36", "32-34", "29-30", "26-28", "24-26"),
                       Buono = c("40-43", "37-40", "35-38", "31-34", "29-31", "27-29"),
                       Ottimo = c("44-49", "41-45", "39-44", "35-39", "32-36", "30-36"),
                       Eccellente = c("50+", "46+", "45+", "40+", "37+", "37+")
                       )
knitr::kable(table_vo2max_donne, caption = "Classificazione del fitness cardio-respiratorio:")

 ```
````

The output in HTML is:
[image: Table rendered in HTML format]

The output in PDF is:
[image: Table rendered in PDF format]

Thanks in advance,

Marco

Comment: Try with `knitr::kable(table_vo2max_donne, caption = "Classificazione del fitness cardio-respiratorio:", escape = FALSE)`. By default "\ is substituted with \textbackslash{}". See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html

Comment: Thanks @stefan , now works in both render. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggest by @stefan it's important to add `escape = FALSE` to the `knitr::kable` command.
So adding:

```
knitr::kable(table_vo2max_donne, caption = "Classificazione del fitness cardio-respiratorio:", escape = FALSE)
```

Render the table in the right way.
Thank to @stefan for the help.